# Can I log on to Windows by drawing a pattern instead of entering a password?

Tags: windows, passwords, password-management, login-screen

Is there any software to replace the Windows password login with pattern login like we do on Android?

There is already software which replaces the login screen with face detection login. There might be other login replacements.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like this: http://sarahlane.typepad.com/sarahword/2004/06/windows_tweak_h.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything like this. But I suppose drawing a pattern would not be that handy to do with a mouse.

You might want to check out this post: [Alternative methods to login to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/139588/alternative-methods-to-login-to-windows)

It discusses some alternatives to Windows login.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows logon is handled by something called the "Graphical Identification and Authentication (GINA) component." Software that enables biometric recognition (fingerprint, facial) replaces the default msgina.dll with a custom GINA. You could always write your own replacement. :-)

I haven't been able to find pattern logon for Windows 7. Maybe you'll have to [wait for Windows 8](http://www.winrumors.com/windows-8-android-like-pattern-logon-screen-demo-video/).